# How to designate a viewport for one camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

If I have multiple cameras in a scene, I would like to choose a 3D view and dedicate a camera to it.

I would like a single 3D view when I choose camera view, Num+0, it will ignore my other camera selections and always show the view of 1 specific camera no matter what. Even if I use that 3D view for other view modes modes it will always come back to the same camera for camera view. Even when animating to switch cameras won't affect the 3D view. Like a monitor directly connected to that camera.

How do I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the view's Local Camera. This must be done in Object Mode.

First, press the button on the toolbar that looks like a rectangle with a chain:

[image: camera-lock-button]

This will unlock the view's camera from the active camera.

Next, go to the View section in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, and choose a Local Camera:

[image: local-camera-select-box]

(I find this useful for cross-eyed stereo, as Blender's built-in stereo mode squishes everything.)

Answer (score 1):

Blender only allows one active camera in a scene and <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> moves the view to the active camera, so you can't setup a different camera view for each viewport.

You can setup as many viewports as you want and you don't have to be viewing from a camera in each viewport. Blender includes an addon called [stored views](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views) which gives you a way to *bookmark* multiple viewport locations, this can provide an easy way to set a viewport back to a desired viewing location, similar to what you would get from a camera.

Answer (score 0):

under view you can set a camera to active.
But maybe all you want is CTRL +ALT  + Q, ea quadview.
When in quad view you can only move around the perspective view.
Or you could duplicate the current view and turn it like you want while keeping the other view unchanged. Or slimply drag a right corner to split current screen if you have two.

Views though are not camera's camera's are things for rendering not for editing, this might be a bit confusing if your background is from autocad or so. incase of autocad CTRL + ALT Q you might like that.